# MariaDB master to master replication auto increment is not sequential

Tags: mysql, mariadb, high-availability

I have two master to master MariaDB server replication with the below settings:

```
server A with 192.168.1.100:
------------------------------
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
server-id       = 1
log-bin         = "mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db        = wordpress
replicate-do-db     = wordpress
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

and:

```
Server B with 192.168.1.200:
---------------------------------
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
server-id               = 2
log-bin                 = "mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db            = wordpress
replicate-do-db         = wordpress
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
```

The replication works great but I have problem with auto increments. As you see they are not sequential. For example:

Server A increments: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and ...

Server B increments: 2, 4, 6, 8 and ...

The problem occurs when I insert 2 records in server A and 1 record in server B, the total primary key of the table will look like this:
ID : 1, 3, 4

As you see number two is missing because I have inserted two records in server A. But I need auto increment to generate sequential numbers since we use them as our invoice numbers.

I know this is the internal mechanism for MariaDB and MySQL databases in order to avoid duplicate keys. but I just wanted to know if there is an alternative HA solution for sequential index replication.

Thank you

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275681/mariadb-master-to-master-replication-auto-increment-is-not-sequential

Answer (score 0):

For Active master-master replication, sequence will not be possible. Let me explain if I can

- Let's say we inserted 2 rows on server 1 (odd indexes) and generated
  index 1 & 3.
- Same got replicated to server 2.
- after that one insert triggered to server 2 and server will find next
  even value that would be 4.

You can use master slave setup instead of master-master if you don't have huge writes.
For HA solution, you can use orchestrator which help to provide auto failover and for queries load balancing use proxy SQL. So below would be setup for complete HA and auto failover

> 2 MySQL node
>
> 1 proxysql
>
> 1 orchestrator

Comment: @sajadkamali - What is the _real_ requirement?  Depending on anything other than uniqueness is folly.

Comment: Rick James, We use IDs as our invoice numbers in our financial systems and invoice numbers should be sequential due to the tax laws in our country

Comment: For this requirement, you can generate invoice number through code always with addition of 1 in previous stored values for which you can add unique constraint  and keep one id column as a primary key